# Doubt about a simple probability problem

Tags: probability

I stumbled upon this problem, and I solved it in two different ways, but I can't understand why the results are different. What i mean to ask is: What am i missing?

**The problem:**

You have a box with 7 balls in it: 3 of them are white, and 4 are black. You take a ball, notice the color, and then you put it back in. You repeat this 5 times. What is the probability of getting just 1 white ball?

**My first approach:**

I know that the probability of finding a white ball doesn't change when i take a ball and put it back in. And the probablity, each time, of finding a white ball is 3/7, and the probability of finding a black ball is 4/7.

So, i just need to:

$$P(Just1 White Ball)=\frac{3}{7}*\frac{4^4}{7^4}$$

**My second approach:**

This is a little more complicated, so i will try to explain how i got there:

- You have 7 balls. But you put the balls back in each time you take one out of the box. You don't care about which one came first. You don't mind the order. So, you can use combinatorics. Taking into account that you're actually reusing the balls, you can say $nCr(7+5-1,5)=nCr(11,5)$. This would be the total amount of possible outcomes. The amount of groups of 5 balls you can make, from the 7 balls you have in the first place, and reusing the balls.
- You have 3 white balls. A part of a favorable outcome would be to have just ONE white ball. So you can ask for the amount of possible ways to arrange 3 balls in groups of 1. You have to take into account, again, that you're reusing the balls. So: $nCr(3+1-1,1)=nCr(3,1)$.
- Finally, you have 4 black balls. A positive or favorable outcome would be that you can arrange those 4 balls, reusing them, into configurations of the 4 balls you have left. So, you want: $nCr(4+4-1,4)=nCr(7,4)$. This would be, again, the amount of ways you can arrange 4 balls into groups of 4 elements, reusing them.

So, the probability of finding ONE white ball would be:

$$\frac{nCr(3,1)*nCr(7,4)}{nCr(11,5)}$$

The problem is that the results are different. I actually feel more comfortable with the first approach, but i think it's a big problem the fact that i can't understand why my second approach is flawed.

I'm very sorry for my english, and thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach needs a factor $5$ because there are five different pulls that could be the white ball.  The probability is then $\frac {3 \cdot 4^4 \cdot 5}{7^5}=\frac{3480}{16807}\approx 0.2285$  I don't follow the logic of the second approach.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Now the results of both approaches are similar. Sorry for not being clear enough in the second approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider each draw as an independent observation and all the ways to obtain the same result:

So you just add the resulting probabilities for each positive combination pull:

$$ P(wbbbb)+P(bwbbb)+P(bbwbb)+P(bbbwb)+P(bbbbw)$$

since each resulting probability is the same, just multiply five times:
$$ P(1w)=\frac{3}{7}*\frac{4}{7}*\frac{4}{7}*\frac{4}{7}*\frac{4}{7} $$
$$ 5P(1w)=5(\frac{3}{7}\frac{4^4}{7^4}) $$

=.04569524603*5= 0.22847623014

Comment: Right. Got that. You put it quite easy to undestand. Thank you!
That would be the problem with the first approach. But the second one does not give the same result (close, but not the same). Do you know what would be the problem with the second approach?

Comment: Let me review your second approach. Will get back with my comments or using combinatorics as you did.

Comment: When you use combinatorics, the wording is very important.  How do you take in consideration that combinations on numerator are multiplied?.  The denominator in this case will not take into account all possibilities.  In the numerator, you are also multiplying two combinations with different grouping size without taking into consideration total white and black balls.  Also in denominator I think you need to state all possibilities to get an answer, which requires permutations not combinations.